# AngularJS Unknown provider error on Karma with value resolved with $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, karma-runner

When I run my Karma tests the following error is displayed:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cartProvider <- cart <- CartCtrl
```

Here is my code:

The value `cart` is resolved here:

```
angular.module 'myApp'
.config ($stateProvider) ->
  $stateProvider.state 'cart',
    url: '/cart'
    resolve:
      cart: (Cart) ->
        Cart.getProducts()
    templateUrl: 'app/cart/cart.html'
    controller: 'CartCtrl'
    controllerAs: 'cart'
```

The controller is here:

```
angular.module 'myApp'
.controller 'CartCtrl', (Cart, cart) ->
  this.cart = cart

  this.removeFromCart = (id) ->
    Cart.removeProduct id

  return this
```

And I guess i need to inject that resolved `cart` on the controller here, but I don't know how:

```
describe 'Controller: CartCtrl', ->

  # load the controller's module
  beforeEach module 'myApp'
  CartCtrl = undefined
  scope = undefined

  # Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach inject ($controller, $rootScope) ->
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    CartCtrl = $controller 'CartCtrl',
      $scope: scope

  it 'should ...', ->
    expect(1).toEqual 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that when testing your controller, the `myApp` config block does not come into play.

You simply need to provide a value for the "cart" and "Cart" injectables, eg

```
var cart, Cart, scope, CartCtrl;

beforeEach(function() {
    var cart = ['some', 'mocked', 'products'],
        Cart = jasmine.createSypObj('Cart', ['removeProduct']);

    module('myApp', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('cart', cart);
        $provide.value('Cart', Cart);
    })

    inject(function($controller, ...) {
        // and so on
    });
});
```

<sub>Apologies for the straight JS, I could **never** get into CoffeeScript</sub>

Comment: This worked! But I also had to specify the cart when initializing the CartCtrl

`CartCtrl = $controller 'CartCtrl',
      $scope: scope
      cart: cart`

Comment: @LuizGustavoSchiller are you sure? I haven't had to do so in my tests but I guess it doesn't hurt to supply all the *locals*

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an inline controller in your state definition to have your resolved `cart` available to the injector. for example:

```
$stateProvider.state 'cart',
  url: '/cart'
  resolve:
    cart: (Cart) ->
      Cart.getProducts()
  templateUrl: 'app/cart/cart.html'
  controller: (cart, Cart) ->
    this.cart = cart

    this.removeFromCart = (id) ->
      Cart.removeProduct id

    return this
  controllerAs: 'cart'
```

I know thats not really ideal, but thats been my experience.

Comment: if you really hate the idea of defining a long controller inline like that.  You could instead define it below the config block as a regular named function, and then just invoke it inline.  The key is that when you define it elsewhere as a regular angular controller on your module, it gets evaluated out of context for the resolved value.  This may be a bug in ui.router though I have not looked into it

Comment: `cart` is being injected fine in my controller. The real problem is when I run the Karma tests.